# Anyone successfully automated PlayStore using Appium

Tags: mobile, automation, appium

I am trying to download\install an app from Google Play Store, then uninstall the same app.

I am able to open Play store but sendkeys method on Google Playstore edit box is not working.

Comment: Try this on Editbox sendKeys("Facebook"+"\n"); it worked for me.

Comment: please share  what have you tried and what error did you face?